# Questions on Subbases For arbitrary product topologies

Tags: general-topology

So in Munkres pg 115 , the text says "Given the collection $S_{\beta} = \{ \pi_{\beta}^{-1}(U_{\beta} | U_{\beta} ^{\circ} \in X\}$ where S = $\bigcup_{\beta \in J} S_{\beta}$ , S is the sub basis.  The basis for the product topology consists of all finite intersections of each $S_{\beta}$.  note that if you intersect non-distinct elements of one of the sets $S_{\beta} $,  $\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(U_{\beta}) \bigcap \pi_{\beta}^{-1}(V_{\beta}) = \pi_{\beta}^{-1}(U_{\beta}\bigcap V_{\beta})$ which is still in $S_{\beta}$.  then for distinct indices we have, B = $\bigcap_{\beta_i \in J} U_{\beta_i } \in \mathbb{B}$ = $\prod_{\alpha \in J}U_{\alpha}$ , now a point $\vec{x} = x_{\alpha} \in B \iff$ x$_{\beta_i} \in U_{\beta_i}$  for each $\beta_i$ .

Here is my question.

The book also says this :  " $U_{\alpha} $denotes the entire space $X_{\alpha}$ if $\alpha \neq \beta_1 , ... , \beta_n$"

I do not understand how $U_{\alpha}$ is the whole space if it is not one of the distinct indices for $\beta_i$.  please help me understand this definition.

I hope that I included the definition correctly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \in B = \pi_{\beta_1}^{-1}(U_{\beta_1}) \cap \ldots \pi_{\beta_n}^{-1}(U_{\beta_n})$ then $x$ $\beta_i$-th coordinate is in $U_{\beta_i}$, but since every other coordinate of $x$ is free to be anything we can say that $$B = \prod_{k \in J} A_k$$
where $A_k = \beta_k$ if $k=\beta_i$ for some $1\leq i \leq n$ and $A_k = X_k$ otherwise (because an element belonging to $B$ may have whatever coordinate at $k$)

Comment: The thing that is confusing, is that how many elements are in the index set J.  so for finitely many of these index elements k = $\beta_i$,  for k$ \in J$.  and for the rest of the elements in J,  then A$_{k^{\cdot}} = X_{k^{\cdot}}$  is this correct way of thinking?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what that means. $J$ is the index of the product of the spaces!

Comment: For tychonoff products, the standard product of arbitrary topological spaces, you'll work a lot with finitely many coordinates of a point